# meteor onLogin cannot modified user's flag

Tags: meteor, accounts

I added some extra fields for user to manually control process while logging via facebook or google.
I trigger autoSendVerificationEmail which works just fine but I cannot set user.user.autoSendVerificationEmail to true; it looks like it is stored locally only; how can I change it?
I used console.logs to check the values and they seem as expected inside the .onLogin ..

```
Accounts.onLogin(function(user) {    
    userID = user.user._id;
    if(!user.user.autoSendVerificationEmail && !user.user.emails[0].verified){
            console.log('user.user.autoSendVerificationEmail:'+user.user.autoSendVerificationEmail);
            user.user.autoSendVerificationEmail = true;//PROBLEM HERE
            console.log('user.user.autoSendVerificationEmail:'+user.user.autoSendVerificationEmail);
            console.log('sending verification email to:'+userID);
            Accounts.sendVerificationEmail(userID);
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I added one line to save my value in Mongo:

```
Meteor.users.update({_id:userID},{$set:{autoSendVerificationEmail:true}});
```

instead of setting the flag to true and it worked